# Запросить подтверждение перед уходом пользователя

Tags: javascript, html5

```
(window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener)((window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'), e => { 
        if(typeof clik != 'boolean') 
            return (e.returnValue = 'Dialog text here')
});
```

В данный момент сделано так, но интересно другое. Возможно ли запросить подтверждение пользователя через функцию

```
window.onpagehide = _ => {
        alert('sdf');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам в таком виде надо?

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = 'Sure?';
    }

    // For Safari
    return 'Sure?';
};
```

Оригинал: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311341/confirmation-before-closing-of-tab-browser

Другой пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858057/ask-for-confirm-when-closing-a-tab/2858115#2858115

Документация: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/window/beforeunload_event#Example

Comment: В onbeforeunload, возможно определить что уход пользователя связан с тем, что пользователь отправляет post запрос, то есть форму?

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов Не уверен, если честно, но думаю можно просто в момент пост запроса, до или после запроса поставить значение в какую-то переменную, чтобы потом можно было достать его из `onbeforeunload`